# Как сделать, чтобы в динамическом списке имя объекту в списке давал пользователь?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть динамический список, который добавляет объекты по их id. Имя так же. Нужно, чтобы имя объекта вводил пользователь в InputField

Comment: Делаете класс с полями id, name, children (List). и всё. делаете древовидную структуру. То, что вводит пользователь идет в один из экземпляров класса в поле name

Comment: Если есть, то покажите ваш код.